# Problem with minicart in safari - wocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

So the problem i have persists on all ios phones but only in safari.

The safari toolbar hides minicart buttons which slides from the right after clicking add to cart. So it makes it impossible to click the buttons at the bottom of the minicart causing cart and checkout pages to be unreachable.

Any idea?

The page is:

[www.mindstring.si](http://www.mindstring.si)

[There are buttons under that bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVENQ.jpg)

[You can see the buttons here before the toolbar covers it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idmld.jpg)

Comment: Would it be possible to place the code you're having issues with into an editable snippet that the community could test and diagnose?

Comment: I dont know what part of the code is the problem...